# How to recreate activity with extra when i change dark mode?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-night-mode

When changing the night mode, I do the following:

```
val nightMode = preferenceRepository.nightMode
preferenceRepository.nightMode = appContext.switchDarkLightMode(nightMode)
```

And here is my extension:

```
fun Context.switchDarkLightMode(currentMode: Int): Int {
    val newMode = when (currentMode) {
        AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO
        AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES
        else -> {
            if (this.isDarkThemeSet()) AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO
            else AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES
        }
    }
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(newMode)
    return newMode
}
```

And as i know:

> setDefaultNightMode() will automatically apply any DayNight changes to
>   any ‘started’ Activities. This means that you no longer have to
>   manually recreate any Activities when you call the API.

**Q**: How can i recreate the activity with the key i need, for example smth like this:

```
fun restartLockableActivity() {
    startActivity(Intent(this, this.javaClass).apply { putExtra(KEY_SKIP_PIN, true) })
    finish()
}
```

UPDATE:
Modified code, but doesn't work:

```
fun Context.switchDarkLightMode(currentMode: Int): Int {
    val newMode = when (currentMode) {
        AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO
        AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES
        else -> {
            if (this.isDarkThemeSet()) AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO
            else AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES
        }
    }
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(newMode)
    val intent = Intent(this, this.javaClass).apply { putExtra(KEY_SKIP_PIN, true) }
    (this as? Activity)?.intent = intent
    return newMode
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [recreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate()) like this:

```
fun restartLockableActivity() {
    intent.putExtra(KEY_SKIP_PIN, true)
    recreate()
}
```

Although it's easier to let users change dark mode in the OS settings and then a configuration change will take care of recreating your app.

Comment: when i call `switchDarkLightMode` mode automatically recreate activity.  Method `restartLockableActivity` i give for example.

Comment: Ah I see, but then you can just use _onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle)_ and in the _onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)_ you take the saved state instead of your extras, right?